# How to calculate the rendered dimensions of an image styled with object-fit: contain

Tags: html, css, image, browser, object-fit

I have this simple html showing an image.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>Image Object Fit</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: contain;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="" />
</body>

</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/hapoqog/edit?html,output

The img element has different properties: `width,height,offsetWidth,offsetHeight,naturalWidth,naturalHeight` but none of them give the dimensions of the rendered image correctly.

How do I calculate the width, height and scale/zoom of the rendered image?

Comment: No need for jsbin links when we have [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` on the editor toolbar).

Comment: I would think this would be a matter of some simple math. `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` get the original width and height  (200 & 300). So divide width by height those to get the aspect ratio. Then multiply that by the current height to get the current rendered width (because the aspect ratio < 1). I'll leave what to do when the aspect ratio is > 1 to you.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

> The replaced content is scaled to maintain its aspect ratio while
> fitting within the element’s content box.

So you have to take both the **aspect ratio** of the image (iAR) and the **aspect ratio** of the container element content box (ctAR) into account.

If the **aspect ratio** of the image > **aspect ratio** of the content box, the rendered image width takes all of the available space.

If the **aspect ratio** of the image < **aspect ratio** of the content box, the rendered image height takes all of the available space.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>Image Object Fit</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: contain;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="" />
</body>
<script>
let img = document.querySelector("img");
img.onload = (e) => {
  let { width, height, naturalWidth, naturalHeight } = img;
  let iAR = naturalWidth / naturalHeight;
  let ctAR = width / height;
  let [w, h] =  iAR >= ctAR ? [width, width / iAR] : [height * iAR, height];
  let s = w / naturalWidth;
  console.log(w, h, s); // rendered width,height and scale
};
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You saved me a lot of time, finally somebody explaining their algorithms!